# Does transferring data from one table to another in google bigquery goes through streaming buffer?

Tags: google-bigquery

When using the insert stream API of GBQ, the data follows the lifecycle as shown below in the image.

But what about the case when you are moving some data from an existing table and inserting into another. Will that cause the new table data to first go through Streaming Buffer or it is instantly available in Columnar Storage.

[image: Lifecycle of a BigQuery streaming insert]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying a table only affects managed storage. It doesn't go through the streaming buffer.